# how to parse text start with Delimiters whitespace-tilde-whitespace " ~ "?

Tags: java, parsing

I want to store 2 things(name and values only ) from text file

anything after ~ sing should be thread as one string called "Name" and anything after ":" colon should be an integer called "Value"

sample output should look like
"Name = " public void end()  "Value =" 5 ...etc

content  of the text file

```
    ~ public void end(): 5

    ~ public void <init>(org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass arg0, gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetricsContainer arg1): 1

    ~ public gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics getMetrics(): 1

    ~ private void incRFC(String arg0, String arg1, org.apache.bcel.generic.Type[] arg2): 1

    ~ public void start(): 1

    ~ void registerMethodInvocation(String arg0, String arg1, org.apache.bcel.generic.Type[] arg2): 1

    ~ public void visitField(org.apache.bcel.classfile.Field arg0): 1

    ~ public void visitJavaClass(org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass arg0): 5

    ~ void registerFieldAccess(String arg0, String arg1): 2

    ~ static String className(org.apache.bcel.generic.Type arg0): 3

    ~ public void registerCoupling(org.apache.bcel.generic.Type arg0): 1

    ~ void <init>(): 1

    ~ public gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics getMetrics(String arg0): 2

    ~ public void printMetrics(gr.spinellis.ckjm.CkjmOutputHandler arg0): 3
```

this is the code i tried to use in headlining the problem

```
        package javaapplication38;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
        import java.nio.file.Files;
        import java.nio.file.Path;
        import java.nio.file.Paths;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        /*  to read CSV file in Java. In this program we will read * list of metrics  stored in CSV file as comma separated values. */
        public class readingtry {


            public static void main(String... args) {
                List<Metrics> metric = readMetricFromCSV("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\alamah.txt");

                // let's print all the metric read from CSV file
                for (Metrics m : metric) {
                    System.out.println(m);
                }
            }

            private static List<Metrics> readMetricFromCSV(String fileName) {
                List<Metrics> metricsss = new ArrayList<>();
                Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

                // create an instance of BufferedReader
                // using try with resource, Java 7 feature to close resources
                try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
                        StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {

                    // read the first line from the text file
                    String line = br.readLine();

                    // loop until all lines are read
                    while (line != null) {


                    String[] attributes = line.split(" ");  // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
                    Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);
                    metricsss.add(valueOfMetric);      // adding metric  into ArrayList
                    line = br.readLine();



                        // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
                        // each line of
                        // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
                        String[] attributes = line.split(" ~ ");

                        Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(attributes);

                        // adding book into ArrayList
                        metricsss.add(valueOfMetric);

                        // read next line before looping
                                         line = br.readLine();
                    }


                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                return metricsss;
            }

            private static Metrics createMetric(String[] metadata) {
                //classname classvalue  
                String name=  (metadata[0]);
                  int value = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1 ]);


               //                                
                return new Metrics(name,value);


            }

        }

        class Metrics {
        private String name;
        private int value;


            public Metrics( String name,int value) {
                this.name = name;
                  this.value=value;

            }

            public String getName() {        return name;    }
            public void setName(String name) {        this.name = name;    }

             public int getvalue() {        return value;    }
            public void setvalue(int value) {        this.value = value;    }


            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "name=  " + name +"value =  " + value+"\n\n" ;
            }

        }
```

Comment: This definitely sounds like a XY problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I just  want to store data from text file to variables  like (gr.spinellis.ckjm.ClassMetrics getMetrics(): ) to variable called "name"  and values(1) to variable called "Value"   and do the same thing for all data inside the  text file  . @Tunaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// read the first line from the text file
String line = br.readLine();

// loop until all lines are read
while (line != null) {

    // use string.split to load a string array with the values from
    // each line of
    // the file, using a comma as the delimiter
    String[] attributes = line.split(" ~ ");
    if (attributes.length == 2) {
        String[] nameValue = attributes[1].split(": ");
        if (nameValue.length == 2) {
            Metrics valueOfMetric = createMetric(nameValue);
            // adding book into ArrayList
            metricsss.add(valueOfMetric);
        }
    }

    // read next line before looping
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you split the String. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "~ public void end(): 5";
    String[] split = input.split(":");

    System.out.println(split[0].substring(split[0].indexOf("~") + 1).trim());
    System.out.println(split[1].trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the your code:

```
public class RegexTest {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str =  "~ public void end(): 5";

    String[] arr1 = str.split("~ ");

    String[] arr2 = arr1[1].split(": ");

    String name = arr2[0], value = arr2[1];

    System.out.println("Name: " + name + ", Value: " + value);
}
}
```

Comment: use this code after you get the line using `readLine()` method.